# How to work out Attrition for Staff members with a Start & End Date in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table with Staff data with columns DateEmployed & TerminationDate.

I would like to work out the number of people that started & left (which I used a count formula) as well as the net growth for all date periods.

The formula would count each DateEmployed as 1 & if an individual does not have a Termination Date then it would not count it.

e.g. 4 people starts in June 2016 & 2 leaves in June 2016 giving me a net value of 2.

The issue arises further as I need a date dimension to view them for each month for each year.

I would like to display all 3 dimensions of data in one graph as well.

[image]

The data should read like the bar graphs consolidated:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDkPs.png)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] (e.g. with some sample CSV data and details about the report you have so far), and be specific about the problem. Currently the post reads more like a task / todo, than as a specific question we could answer.

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks, will do.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in every case is to create a calendar/date table. Fortunately calendar tables are easy to create in Power BI. With an expression you can create it.

In Power BI / `Modeling` tab / `New Table` icon, you can create a custom date table using this expression:

```
DateTable = CALENDAR (DATE(2016,1,1), DATE(2016,12,31))
```

This expression generates dates from `2016-1-1` to `2016-12-31` so if your data expands to a wider range you have to modify it to suit to your requeriment.

Create these measures:

**Starting:** Measure counting the people starting in each month or year.

```
Starting =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Table'[FullName] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table' ),
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                'Table',
                NOT ISBLANK ( [DateEmployed] )
                    && MONTH ( EARLIER ( 'Table'[DateEmployed] ) ) = MONTH ( MAX ( DateTable[Date] ) )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Ending:** Measure for counting the people ending in each month or year.

```
Ending =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Table'[FullName] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table' ),
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                'Table',
                NOT ISBLANK ( [TerminationDate] )
                    && MONTH ( EARLIER ( 'Table'[TerminationDate] ) )
                        = MONTH ( MAX ( DateTable[Date] ) )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Net:** Total for each month:

```
Total = ABS([Starting] - [Ending])
```

Now in a bar chart or any visualization set the measures something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @alejandrozuleta.

It is almost there but the calculation is not working for the Starting measure but the Ending makes sense. It is showing a very high value for starting.

Starting = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Staff'[FullName] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Staff' ),
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                'Staff',
                NOT ISBLANK ( [DateEmployed] )
                    && MONTH ( EARLIER ( 'Staff'[DateEmployed] ) )
                     = MONTH ( MAX ( DateTable[Date] ) )
            )
        )
    )
)

Comment: The Ending does not add up for December 2016 but works for other Months in the year. So, it is not calculating 100%.

Comment: @Rush, what should the result be then?

Comment: It should be much lower like if I do a count formula on the FullName it would give me figures that made sense but the formula you gave me does not add up correctly.

Comment: @Rush, Note the sample graph I used was generated with the sample data you posted in your OP originally, and it shows correct result based on that data. In the sample you posted if you merge both charts in only one how will you know which black bar corresponds to starters or leavers?

Comment: I found the issue, it was in my data which for my current staff (people who are currently active) having a date of 1899/12/31 in their End Date which I need to exclude in the Ending formula. How would I modify the formula to exclude that date?

Comment: @Rush, are you using the formulas provided in my answer?

Comment: yes I am. I am doing some sanity testing to ensure it makes sense.

Comment: @Rush, Did you create the calendar table?, if you created it then you should delete that date from that table. And it will not be included in the chart.

Comment: I have, my DateTable starts from 1998 going up. For some reason, the formula is not counting correctly e.g. for year-month 16-10 it matches up with the date table but it gives me an incorrect total for that year-month.